# Cannot force a Picker to show up on button press

Tags: codenameone

In my CN1 app there is a `Multibutton`. When I press on it I want the `Picker` action defined in its `addActionListener` method to be triggered. To do so I based my snippet on https://www.codenameone.com/manual/events.html.

So in the `Multibutton` `addActionListener` method I added

```
            listeners.fireActionEvent(new ActionEvent(picker, ActionEvent.Type.PointerPressed));
```

where listeners is an `EventDispatcher` object and picker is a `Picker` object.

In the picker `addActionListener` I added

```
            listeners.addListener(e);
```

But the Picker is not fired when I press the Multibutton although when I press on the picker (which is laidout for testing purpose) and validate a selection it prints out that the event is `PointerPressed` and the actualComponent is `Picker`.

So is it achievable to directly "open" the Picker when the user presses a (multi)button so that the user does not have to press the buttton, then press the Picker and finally validate the selection. They only have to press the button and validate the selection.

**EDIT**
I added

```
   listeners.addListener(new ActionEvent(picker, ActionEvent.Type.PointerPressed));
```

before the `picker.addActionListener` method but now I get 
    `ActionEvent cannot be cast to ActionListener` regarding the call to `fireActionEvent`.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to open a Picker when the user clicks a (Multi)Button.
Try this code:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
MultiButton multiButton = new MultiButton("MultiButton");
Picker picker = new Picker();
multiButton.addActionListener(l -> {
    picker.pressed();
    picker.released();
});
picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
picker.setStrings("String 1", "String 2", "String 3");
picker.setSelectedStringIndex(0);
picker.addActionListener(l -> {
    Log.p("Picker selected string: " + picker.getSelectedString());
});
hi.add(multiButton).add(picker);
hi.show();
```

Comment: Simple and efficient! It works as expected. Still I am wondering why there is this `fireActionEvent`. Anyway thank you  @FrancescoGalgani

Comment: `listeners.addListener(new ActionEvent(picker, ActionEvent.Type.PointerPressed));` is adding an action event to a listener. You are looking for `fireActionEvent`

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I messed up everything in this snippet! Then I tried to create a `new ActionListener<ActionEvent>()` that I added to the `listeners` but could not fire it up with `fireActionEvent`. @FrancescoGalgani's solution is perfect. I don't know if I actually have to go through both states (ie `pressed` and `released`).

Comment: If you do one of them it won't work so you need both.